# compute the hamming distance as a probability of similarity to be between 0 and 1

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

I am using image hashes to compute the Hamming score. What I now require is to channel this value through a function that yields a similarity score ranging between 0 to 1, where smaller Hamming values are nearer to 1 and larger Hamming values are nearer to 0. My initial method of calculating this is `1 - (Hamming_score/length_of_hash)`. This is effective only when the Hamming score is less than the length of the hash, which is `16`. For Hamming scores greater than `16`, I receive values less than 0, which is undesirable. I could rectify this by reversing the formula to `1 - (length_of_hash/Hamming_score)`, but the results from this formula do not adhere to the condition that larger Hamming scores should have values closer to 0. here is my current function which isnt helping.

```
def calculate_similarity(hash1, hash2):
    
    hamming_distance = sum(bit1 != bit2 for bit1, bit2 in zip(hash1, hash2))
    hash_length = len(hash1)
    
    similarity = 1 - (hamming_distance / hash_length)
    
    # Ensure the similarity score is within the valid range [0, 1]
    similarity = max(0, min(1, similarity))
    
    return similarity
```

Any help is appreciated.